# Emulate keystroke in other window

Tags: batch-file, executable, keystroke

This may be a cardinal programming sin, but what's the easiest and quickest way via executable or batch file to bring focus to Window X and hit keystroke Y? This won't be reused, and X and Y can be hard-coded if necessary.

edit: on a Windows machine

Comment: What platform are we talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or use win32 API as [MusiGenesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413944/emulate-keystroke-in-other-window/1413967#1413967) suggested.

Comment: AutoHotKey seems to be the quickest and dirtiest solution here.
No need to reinvent the wheel.

Something like:

IfWinExist Program-X
{
    WinActivate
}
else
{
    Run Program-X
    WinWait Program-X
    WinActivate
}
Send {Y}

Answer (score 2):

Use the Win32 API calls **FindWindowEx** and **SendMessage** (or **SendNotifyMessage** if you want control to return to your application immediately without waiting for the receiving application to process the message).

Assuming this is Windows, of course.

This isn't really much of a sin, by the way.  There are much more evil things that a program can do than sending keystrokes to other applications (e.g. randomly deleting files, emailing porn to your grandmother etc.).